# Update of XJC / Jakarta causes `Map<QName, String> otherAttributes` to be generated, which subsequently causes runtime issues

Tags: jaxb, xjc, jakarta-migration

Upgrading to jakarta caused some issues for me.

I'm using the following maven plugin:

```xml
<groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
<artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb40-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

And I use episodal compilation (have libraries). Suddenly I'm facing the following problem:

```
Can't have @XmlAnyAttribute when a base class has it already.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute()
```

Closer inspection reveals that XJC suddenly generates the following field:

```java
        @XmlAnyAttribute
        private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<>();
```

which it did not generate before. How can I disable this?

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Rick.. missed your request in my holiday period. We've got a temp fix (overriding selectively generated classes with binding). I'll try to make MRE.

Comment: MRE: https://github.com/sjaakd/jreproducer_jaxb .. However for some reason it does not yet show the same behaviourruntime. It does generate the troublesome 'otherAttributes'. I'll see if I can add more to the xsd to trigger the fault

Comment: Managed to reproduce. But I guess the problem is in JAXB / XJC. See also: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the root cause is in [JAXB-RI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri), see [#1735](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1735), [#1356](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1356) and [#1146](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1146).

However, the next release (no ETA) of [hisrc-basicjaxb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) will include a new XJC plugin named [fixOtherAttributes](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/commit/44abe67f2454230e4118d8d327c70d05d65c1481#diff-6b006be1d29b9282db67c847ba75979f639b2cc969431c1edb80da636bbde85a). This plugin iterates over the XJC class outlines and removes duplicate `otherAttributes` field(s) together with their associated `@XmlAnyAttribute`, `getter` and `setter` methods.

> **Note:** This plugin requires JAR(s) from previous episodes be added, as dependencies, to the XJC classpath. In particular, *configured as dependencies* in the Maven plugin used to run XJC. Reflection is used to detect the *original* `otherAttributes` field from the previous episode's JAR(s). For a sample configuration, see [hisrc-basicjaxb:higher/tests/episodes/b/pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/tests/episodes/b/pom.xml).

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the [hisrc-basicjaxb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) project.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I spotted that you were the maintainer. Really appreciate that you took over the good work. Thanks for your effort. I'll keep an eye out for the plugin.

Comment: The [FixOtherAttributes](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/plugins/src/main/java/org/jvnet/basicjaxb/plugin/fixotherattributes/FixOtherAttributes.java) is available in [HiSrc BasicJAXB, v2.2.0](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/releases/tag/2.2.0).